# Как из таблицы webSQL получить данные в виде переменной?

Tags: javascript, html, база-данных, websqldatabase

Нужно что бы логин и пароль представлялись в виде переменной. Как написать правильно запрос?

```html
<html>
<body>
<script>
    db = openDatabase("DATAPASS", "0.1", "LOGIN DATA", 200000);
    if (!db)
    {
        alert("Failed");
    }
    db.transaction(function (trans)
    {
        trans.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS pass (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC, login TEXT, password TEXT)");
        trans.executeSql("INSERT INTO pass IF NOT EXISTS (login, password) values(?,?)", ["admin", "admin"])
        trans.executeSql("INSERT INTO pass(login, password) values(?,?)", ["a123dmin1", "adm123in1"])
        trans.executeSql("DELETE FROM pass WHERE login = ?", ["admin"])

    })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При SELECT'е нужна еще функция в которую приходят результаты. Вот такой код возвращает все пары login => password:

```js
        db = openDatabase("DATAPASS", "0.1", "LOGIN DATA", 200000);
        db.transaction(function(trans) {
            trans.executeSql('SELECT login, password  FROM pass', [], function(trans, result) {
                var len = result.rows.length, i;                    
                for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {                    
                    console.log(result.rows.item(i).login + " => " + result.rows.item(i).password);
                }
            }, function(trans, e) {
                console.log("Error");
            });
        });
```